# Which one is correct of the two sentences?

Tags: grammar

1. you have to do it right from the start
2. you have to do it right from the  beginning

which one is correct? if both, are they both natural to use while speaking?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in your examples between "start" and "beginning." Alas, you have inadvertently run into a problem with English idiom. *Right* can mean in the right way, i.e., properly, correctly. Thus

> **[1a]** You have to do it (right) (from the start)

can mean

> **[1b]** You have to do it correctly and you have to do it correctly when you begin your task.

The parentheses in 1a indicate that there are two adverbial phrases, one of manner ("right") and one of time ("from the start").

However, *right* can mean exactly. We see can see this in the command

> **[2]** Come here **right** now!

which means come here at exactly the present moment, i.e., immediately. This leads to the idiomatic phrase "right from the start," which means exactly at the beginning. Suppose my trainer at the gym is supervising some exercise I'm doing, and I'm holding my breath:

> **Trainer**: You're not breathing. You have to breathe.
>    **Me**: When?
>   **Trainer**: **[1c]** You have to do it (right from the start).

He means I have to breathe throughout the exercise beginning when I start the exercise. Note in 1c the parentheses indicate that there is one (idiomatic) adverbial phrase meaning exactly at the beginning.

So how do you know whether it's 1a or 1c? The only way to tell is context, knowing more about the situation in which the sentence appears.